# How to access child variables from a parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have 3 classes, Person, Student, and Teacher. Student and Teacher extend Person. How can I access instance variables from within Person? Like if Student and Teacher both have an internal list of names, how can I access both name arrays from within the parent class?

```
class Person
{
   private String name;
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
        return this.name;
   }
    public void printAllNames() { //<-- How do you do this?
        for(Student s : students) //can't access students array
           System.out.println(s.getName());
        for(Teacher t : teachers)
           System.out.println(t.getName());
    }
}

class Student extends Person
{
   protected Student[] students;
   Student(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
      students[students.length] = this;
   }
}

class Teacher extends Person
{
   protected Teacher[] teachers;
   Teacher(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
      teacher[teachers.length] = this;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class design is incorrect. Your `Student` class should not contain a field `students` as other students are not part of a `Student` instance (i.e. composition should not be used here). Instead you should create lists of students outside of these classes if they are required. Same for teachers of course.

A student could have a list of friends, but such relations are better stored outside the class itself as well. The list of friends does is not *part of* a student. What does need to be part of student depends on what you are trying to model (an address could be part of student if that helps to define student for administration purposes).

If you want to access fields of a higher level class you could downcast to `Student` from `Person` but again, that would normally be considered as a technical solution for a design problem.

Comment: hmm I see. What about the idea of a static array of students within each student? Ok still bad design as you said because each student should know about other students

Comment: You could have a `Students.ALL` constant, but I would rather just create and register the students in some registration class (possibly part of `School`). You should model the school world, so taking hints from the *domain* in the real world is usually the best method of making a design. Later on you'll automatically get an itch if a design isn't modeling the domain correctly :)

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do if `Students.ALL` is a good idea; it's about abstraction levels. You can have less complicated design for smaller problems. You shouldn't go overboard and include the floor tiles in the design :P

Comment: So let's say this was an interview question and I'm allowed only those 3 classes (it was), I should keep a const static array of students in the Person class and update that array from child classes

Comment: I'd use a static initializer for that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. (going to look up static initializers now)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the issues with the design and the use of arrays as others have mentioned, if you want to print the names depending on whether it's a student and teacher, you should make printAllNames abstract and have the descendant classes provide their own print implementation. The base class should not know about specifics of properties or methods in subclasses.

```
class Person
{
    ...

    public abstract void printAllNames();
}


class Student extends Person
{
    ...

    public void printAllNames() {
        for (Student s : students)
            System.out.println(s.getName());
    }
}

class Teacher extends Person
{
    ...

    public void printAllNames() {
        for (Teacher t : teachers)
            System.out.println(t.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Ignoring issues with design" i'm actually trying to learn OOP so please don't ignore issues with design. But the question of visibility is unchanged depending on array vs map so that shouldn't matter for learning purposes.

Comment: Others have already pointed our the flaws in your design so i figured I tackle a different aspect with the issue of how you would get around the issue of not having access to fields in the subclass. The bottom line with the design is that you need to remodel where teachers and students should be stored. It doesn't make sense to store them in each instance of the person - it would mean student/teacher has their own list. You could make students and teachers static, which would make more sense, but a better way would be to make a single School class which has the list of teachers and students.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is having issue in **array.length()** because there is no any method like **length()**. you can access that by **array.length**.

second there is no **name** variable in your **Student** class and you made **name** as **private** field in Person Class change that to **public** or **protected**.

third you can pass argument in your method like

```
public void printAllNames(Student[] students, Teacher[] teachers)
```

and check once.